# Can't open files created in Ubuntu from Windos

Tags: 14.04, files, ntfs

I've created a video with KDENLIVE in Ubuntu. I've saved it in a NTFS Partition where I keep my important data. Then I restarted and booted Windows 8.1 and now I can't open the file from Windows. In Ubuntu works fine.

It says it can't find the file when I double click it to open it.

It is not the first time it happens.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the format that the video was saved? Can you access other video files (if any) in the partition?

Comment: try write down the extension of the file at the end of the title according to your converted file type, .avi, .mp3, .mp4, .ogv and etc. Windows need this to identified the type of the file.

Comment: One more thing to check is NTFS file permissions. Depending on how do you mount your NTFD partition in Linux the newly created file might get owner/groups NTFS permissions that Windows consider as 'this user is not authorized, deny him access'. Do you know how to see them? (Properties - Security - Permissions) Are they OK?

Comment: as said, try to edit your question to more clear one. it may caused by bad filename(using windows forbidden characters like ":") or corrupted file system.

Comment: Sorry for taking soooo long to respond but I was expecting this to send me an email in case of any answer which it didn't do. I've looked in the preferences of my profile I can't seem to find a way to make it send me an email when a new comment is placed. Anyway, my problem is I can't seem to even open a folder that I've created in Ubuntu when I try to open it in windows so it isn't a problem of file format. I don't see any difference in the permisions (looking by right clicking in the folder and going to permissions from Ubuntu) of a folder created in windows and one created in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 doesn't do a real shutdown, so if you write to the ntfs filesystem while the windows system in fact is only in sleep it can lead to filesystem corruption an errors. You have to look up how you can force windows to do a real shutdown or use ext explorer to access the linux filesystem from windows.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with that. I have disable the fast boot option in Windows so it actually shuts down.